# AsyncStorage is not working, the value always disappears when the application reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to save an array of object to device using AsyncStorage, I have used AsyncStorage for save my jwt token and it working well. But when i tried to save an array of object it wasn't working here is my code :

```
  const storeCart = async (value) => {
    try {
      const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(value);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(`cart-${user.id}`, jsonValue);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    } finally {
      const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem(`cart-${user.id}`);
      if (jsonValue != null) {
        console.log(
          'this is from async storage after save',
          JSON.parse(jsonValue),
          user.id,
        );
      }
    }
  };

  const getCart = async () => {
    try {
      const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem(`cart-${user.id}`);
      if (jsonValue != null) {
        setCarts(JSON.parse(jsonValue));
        console.log('carts after refresh the app', jsonValue, user.id);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };
```

[image: The Console Log]

I have tried to console log the result after setItem, and it was saved successly, but when i reload the app and tried to console.log, it return and empty array, the key is already correct, and i have console log the `user id` too for make sure.

Here's the full code, if needed :

```
import React, { useState, createContext, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import AuthenticationContext from '../authentication/AuthenticationContext';

const CartsContext = createContext();

export const CartsContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthenticationContext);
  const [carts, setCarts] = useState([]);

  const storeCart = async (value) => {
    try {
      const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(value);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(`cart-${user.id}`, jsonValue);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    } finally {
      const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem(`cart-${user.id}`);
      if (jsonValue != null) {
        console.log(
          'this is from async storage after save',
          JSON.parse(jsonValue),
          user.id,
        );
      }
    }
  };

  const getCart = async () => {
    try {
      const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem(`cart-${user.id}`);
      if (jsonValue != null) {
        setCarts(JSON.parse(jsonValue));
        console.log('carts after refresh the app', jsonValue, user.id);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    storeCart(carts);
  }, [carts, user]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getCart();
  }, [user]);

  const searchByMerchant = (merchantId) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < carts.length; i++) {
      if (carts[i].merchantId === merchantId) {
        return carts[i];
      }
    }
  };

  const searchByItem = (itemId, arrayOfItems) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfItems.length; i++) {
      if (itemId === arrayOfItems[i].productId) {
        return arrayOfItems[i];
      }
    }
  };

  const deletePerMerchant = (merchantId) => {
    return carts.filter((x) => {
      return x.merchantId != merchantId;
    });
  };

  const deletePerItem = (itemId, arrayOfItems) => {
    return arrayOfItems.filter((x) => {
      return x.productId != itemId;
    });
  };

  const addItem = (merchantId, productId, qty) => {
    let merchantCheck = searchByMerchant(merchantId);
    let temp = null;

    if (merchantCheck) {
      let itemCheck = searchByItem(productId, merchantCheck.items);
      if (itemCheck) {
        let itemAfterRemoveSelectedItem = deletePerItem(
          productId,
          merchantCheck.items,
        );
        temp = deletePerMerchant(merchantId);
        if (qty === 0) {
          if (itemAfterRemoveSelectedItem.length === 0) {
            setCarts([...temp]);
          } else {
            setCarts([
              ...temp,
              ...[
                {
                  merchantId,
                  items: [...itemAfterRemoveSelectedItem],
                },
              ],
            ]);
          }
        } else {
          setCarts([
            ...temp,
            ...[
              {
                merchantId,
                items: [
                  ...itemAfterRemoveSelectedItem,
                  ...[{ productId, qty: qty }],
                ],
              },
            ],
          ]);
        }
      } else {
        temp = deletePerMerchant(merchantId);
        setCarts([
          ...temp,
          ...[
            {
              merchantId,
              items: [...merchantCheck.items, ...[{ productId, qty }]],
            },
          ],
        ]);
      }
    } else {
      if (qty > 0) {
        setCarts([...carts, ...[{ merchantId, items: [{ productId, qty }] }]]);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <CartsContext.Provider value={{ carts, addItem }}>
      {children}
    </CartsContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default CartsContext;
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is happening because the `cart` value is being overwritten when you reload the app because the `useEffect` is called each time you reload the app.
The `setCarts` is being called after adding something in cart, and therefore the first `useEffect` (which has in deps `[cart, user]`) is being called too and it sets correctly the data in local storage. But afterwards, if you reload the app, the same `useEffect` is being called again and the `cart = []` is being set into the local storage.
I would solve this by giving up to the first useEffect and setting directly the data into local storage without having any state related to it.

```js
import React, { useState, createContext, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import AuthenticationContext from '../authentication/AuthenticationContext';

const CartsContext = createContext();

export const CartsContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthenticationContext);

  const storeCart = async (value) => {
    try {
      const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(value);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(`cart-${user.id}`, jsonValue);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    } finally {
      const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem(`cart-${user.id}`);
      if (jsonValue != null) {
        console.log(
          'this is from async storage after save',
          JSON.parse(jsonValue),
          user.id,
        );
      }
    }
  };

  const getCart = async () => {
    try {
      const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem(`cart-${user.id}`);
      if (jsonValue != null) {
        storeCart(JSON.parse(jsonValue));
        console.log('carts after refresh the app', jsonValue, user.id);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };



  useEffect(() => {
    getCart();
  }, [user]);

  const searchByMerchant = (merchantId) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < carts.length; i++) {
      if (carts[i].merchantId === merchantId) {
        return carts[i];
      }
    }
  };

  const searchByItem = (itemId, arrayOfItems) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfItems.length; i++) {
      if (itemId === arrayOfItems[i].productId) {
        return arrayOfItems[i];
      }
    }
  };

  const deletePerMerchant = (merchantId) => {
    return carts.filter((x) => {
      return x.merchantId != merchantId;
    });
  };

  const deletePerItem = (itemId, arrayOfItems) => {
    return arrayOfItems.filter((x) => {
      return x.productId != itemId;
    });
  };

  const addItem = (merchantId, productId, qty) => {
    let merchantCheck = searchByMerchant(merchantId);
    let temp = null;

    if (merchantCheck) {
      let itemCheck = searchByItem(productId, merchantCheck.items);
      if (itemCheck) {
        let itemAfterRemoveSelectedItem = deletePerItem(
          productId,
          merchantCheck.items,
        );
        temp = deletePerMerchant(merchantId);
        if (qty === 0) {
          if (itemAfterRemoveSelectedItem.length === 0) {
            storeCart([...temp]);
          } else {
            storeCart([
              ...temp,
              ...[
                {
                  merchantId,
                  items: [...itemAfterRemoveSelectedItem],
                },
              ],
            ]);
          }
        } else {
          storeCart([
            ...temp,
            ...[
              {
                merchantId,
                items: [
                  ...itemAfterRemoveSelectedItem,
                  ...[{ productId, qty: qty }],
                ],
              },
            ],
          ]);
        }
      } else {
        temp = deletePerMerchant(merchantId);
        storeCart([
          ...temp,
          ...[
            {
              merchantId,
              items: [...merchantCheck.items, ...[{ productId, qty }]],
            },
          ],
        ]);
      }
    } else {
      if (qty > 0) {
        storeCart([...carts, ...[{ merchantId, items: [{ productId, qty }] }]]);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <CartsContext.Provider value={{ carts, addItem }}>
      {children}
    </CartsContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default CartsContext;
```